Add types for slot in VueJs 3
In react js library is a type that describes the children - ReactNode.
Ex:
interface Props {
  children: ReactNode; 
}

// Define a functional component with the specified props type
const Component = ({ children }: { children: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{children}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

I did not find a solution to type slots in vue js. For example i have the next component:
<template>
  <div>
   <slot/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps();
</script>


How to type the slot to accept a specific type?

This question is similar to: How do I setup a vue slot type as a simple string not a component. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Maybe you are looking for something like Scoped Slots.
Because it seems that your example does not make sense in typification.
If you look at React Node Object Type - it's actually you can past in slot:

Boolean (which is ignored)
null or undefined (which is ignored)
Number
String
A React element (result of JSX)
An array of any of the above, possibly a nested one

